# Partial Function Application in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a partial function from any function.

Here is a working example:

```js
function partial(fn) {
    const argc = fn.length;
    const argv = [];

    return function part(...args) {
        argv.push(...args);
        return argv.length >= argc ? fn(...argv) : part;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
function foo(a, b, c, d) {
    return `foo: ${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}`;
}

console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2, 3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2)(3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1)(2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)()(1, 2)()(3)()(4) ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

However, I'm not completely happy with it because of `argv.push(...args);`.

Is there a better, shorter, or more canonical way to make a partial function application in JavaScript?

Edit:
Replaced deprecated `arguments` with [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `...args`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interesting question,

I have never seen a partial functional application like that, I am used to see something more like

```
function partial2(f, ...args) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(this, args.concat(...arguments));
  };
}

console.log(partial2(foo, 1, 2)(3,4)); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Where you create once the partial application, and that's it.
To me, that is the more canonical way.

Your code is in a way more flexible and fun. The only thing I can provide is to note that `Array.push` returns the new count elements, and `Array.length` provides the current count of elements. This means you could just skip the request of `argv.length` and directly work with the return value of `argv.push(...args)`

```
function partial3(f) {
  const argc = f.length, argv = [];
  return function partialFunction(...args) {
    return argv.push(...args) >= argc ? f(...argv) : partialFunction;
  };
}
```

And actually, the caching of `argc` seems a bit overkill, you only use `f.length` once.

```
function partial3(f) {
  const argv = [];
  return function partialFunction(...args) {
    return argv.push(...args) >= f.length ? f(...argv) : partialFunction;
  };
}
```

Final thought, this might need some more fiddling.

```
const myPartial = partial3(foo)(1, 2, 3);
console.log( myPartial('a') );
console.log( myPartial('b') );
console.log( myPartial('c') );
```

The expectation of a partial is that this should return

```
foo: 1, 2, 3, a
foo: 1, 2, 3, b
foo: 1, 2, 3, c
```

but it returns

```
foo: 1, 2, 3, a
foo: 1, 2, 3, a
foo: 1, 2, 3, a
```

because the partial function keeps too much state...

Belows is a snippet with the different functions and some tests;

```js
function partial(fn) {
    const argc = fn.length;
    const argv = []

    return function part(...args) {
        argv.push(...args);
        return argv.length >= argc ? fn(...argv) : part;
    }
}

function partial2(f, ...args) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(this, args.concat(...arguments));
  };
}

function partial3(f) {
  const argc = f.length, argv = [];
  return function partialFunction(...args) {
    return argv.push(...args) >= argc ? f(...argv) : partialFunction;
  };
}


function foo(a, b, c, d) {
    return `foo: ${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}`;
}

console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2, 3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2)(3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1, 2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)(1)(2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial(foo)()(1, 2)()(3)()(4) ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4

console.log( partial2(foo, 1, 2)(3,4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4

console.log( partial3(foo)(1, 2, 3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial3(foo)(1, 2)(3, 4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial3(foo)(1, 2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial3(foo)(1)(2)(3)(4)       ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log( partial3(foo)()(1, 2)()(3)()(4) ); // => foo: 1, 2, 3, 4

const myPartial = partial3(foo)(1, 2, 3);
console.log( myPartial('a') );
console.log( myPartial('b') );
console.log( myPartial('c') );
```

Comment: I see a meaningful usage of the return value of `push` for the first time :) `return argv.push(...args) >= argc ? ` I always thought it should return a ref to the array itself.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov Fully agreed, if I wanted length, I could have called `.length` on the returned list.